# Нужны ли кавычки (и большая буква) после двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда домики местных жителей поредели, обратился к прохожему: в правильном ли направлении двигаюсь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Да, оформление верное,** двоеточие ставится при бессоюзной связи с изъяснительным значением.

**Пояснение**

Запятой здесь не обойдешься, так как в данной структуре предложения явно присутствует пауза.

Оформлять вопрос как обычную речь не имеет смысла, так как выделительная способность прямой речи не вписывается в контекст.

Другие варианты

Когда домики местных жителей поредели, я спросил у прохожего,  в правильном ли направлении я иду в город.

Когда домики местных жителей поредели, я спросил у прохожего: "По этой дороге я дойду до города?"